# Generalised Binary Operation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, soft-question, binary-operations, associativity

In algebra, we study sets with binary operations satisfying certain properties. However, sometimes that the calculation is undefined for some ordered pairs, such as $a\div 0$ for any complex number $a$.

My question is, do people study algebra systems with an operation which is similar to binary operation but allowing the operation to be undefined for some ordered pairs? That is, give a set $X$, are people interested in maps from a subset of $X\times X\to X$ satisfying some properties such as associativity and commutativity (when the product is defined)?

Comment: They are called "partial binary operations". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_operation#Terminology

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_algebra, and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_inverse_semigroup (both going beyond binary operations or partial binary operations).

Comment: Thank you so much for your comments!